# Grpc Client throws Grpc.Core.RpcException (Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.)

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I spend the last three days *(Reading Docus, Trying different vesions of VS and .NET, check questions in Stackoverflow, issues in github, ...)* about my Grpc client, the server start fine but the client never work, I tried **Grpcurl it's works fine** but **C# client never works** and throws Grpc.Core.RpcException here is a smaple:

```
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Bad gRPC response. Response protocol downgraded to HTTP/1.1.")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
```

This issue happed in **VS2019, VS2022 (Net5, Net6)**.
Is there anything that I can do reagrding this? because we are going to use Grpc on our next project.

Comment: May need to update kernel : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/http2?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-5.0.  Can't tell exectly  hwere the issue is.  Curl may be using its own protocol and not the operating system, while c# may be using operating system.  Also curl may be using http 1.0 and not http 1.1.  Error indicates connection was attempted with http/2 and then tried 1.1.  Yoru may need to foce http 1.0.

Comment: I will check that @jdweng

Comment: I have the same issue, works with grpcui but errors on response in the actual app (Blazor WASM in this case). The call itself does reach the server.

Comment: I solve the issue by reinstall my Operating System, I don't have any information in this regard. @jdweng told me it maybe issue in Kernel, I don't have another options and I'm running out of time so I did that.

Comment: Operating System may also update the Kernel.