# ASP.NET CORE 5.0 TLS 1.2 issue on linux but on asp.net core 3.1 are working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I have a problem with TLS 1.2 in asp.net core 5.0 and linux.
It's happening only in asp.net core 5.0, the same code run on asp.net core 3.1

SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL on Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 using HttpClient and net5.0

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillHandshakeBufferAsync>g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|182_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp2ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am sharing a console app bellow that you should see to know about this issue.
unfortunately I cannot share the credentials of the application and for reasons of nda neither the provider that is consuming its api. We also have our ips whitelisted on a firewall.
But I share the code so you can see everything I have tried

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                 .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                 {
                     services.AddHttpClient("configured-certificate")
                      .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
                      {
                          return new HttpClientHandler()
                          {
                              CheckCertificateRevocationList = false,
                              UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                              ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                              SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11,
                              ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => ServerCertificateCustomValidation(message, cert, chain, errors),
                              AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                              //ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator,
                              //ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; },
                              CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
                          };
                      });

                     services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
                     services.AddLogging((configure) =>
                     {
                         configure.AddConsole();
                         configure.AddDebug();
                     });
                     var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
                     Console.Write($"Environtment: {env.EnvironmentName}\n");
                     var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                        
                     hostContext.Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
                 })
                 .UseConsoleLifetime();

            var host = builder.Build();

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                 (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
                 {
                     return true;
                 };

            try
            {
                var myService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITestService>();
                var pageContent = await myService.GetPage();

                Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred.");
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private static bool ServerCertificateCustomValidation(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, X509Certificate2 certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslErrors)
        {
            //It is possible inpect the certificate provided by server
            Console.WriteLine($"Requested URI: {requestMessage.RequestUri}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Effective date: {certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Exp date: {certificate.GetExpirationDateString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Issuer: {certificate.Issuer}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {certificate.Subject}");

            //Based on the custom logic it is possible to decide whether the client considers certificate valid or not
            Console.WriteLine($"Errors: {sslErrors}");

            return true;
            //return sslErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
        }
    }

    public interface ITestService
    {
        Task<string> GetPage();
    }

    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public TestService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetPage()
        {
            var uri = "https://secureuri";

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("configured-certificate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("basic", "fglsdhjgoñisdjfhgoishdfg=");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("br"));

            var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("request.xml");
            var data = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, data);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return $"StatusCode: {response.StatusCode}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The publish profile is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>D:\Test</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I have results on asp.net core 3 and curl on the same server

```
root@skynet:# curl -u user:passwd -kv https://xmldirect.ehi.com/services30/OTA30SOAP
*   Trying 12.43.130.115:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xmldirect.ehi.com (12.43.130.115) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; postalCode=63105; ST=Missouri; L=St. Louis; street=600 Corporate Park Dr.; O=Enterprise Holdings Inc.; CN=xmldirect.ehi.com
*  start date: Mar 12 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 12 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET /services30/OTA30SOAP HTTP/1.1
> Host: xmldirect.ehi.com
> Authorization: Basic fglsdhjgoñisdjfhgoishdfg=
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 05 Jul 2021 23:58:48 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

***Live Environtment***

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.2s 28 May 2019
```

***Test Environtment***

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020
```

Asp.net core 3.1 Ciphers on Client Hello (28 suites)

[image]

Asp.net core 5.0 Cipher on Client Hello (9 suites)

[image]

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55227

With the good case, client offers bunch of ciphers and server will pick Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d) (packet 6 -> ServerHello)
With 5.0 the default ciphers are limit to what is currently believed to be strong and safe ciphers. The one above is not in the list

Comment: This seems similar to following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128693/grpc-client-throws-grpc-core-rpcexception-response-protocol-downgraded-to-http#comment120625567_68128693  Either reinstall the operating system or kernel.

Comment: I have tested and probed on 3 servers ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: Is it working or are you still having issue?

Comment: I still having this issue. ;(

Comment: Try upgrading openssl on linux.  Also see : https://wiki.debian.org/ContinuousIntegration/TriagingTips/openssl-1.1.1

Comment: @jdweng but the problem is asp.net core 5.0 becase in asp.net core 3.1 works fine. And if i use the curl command works too.

Comment: The error message says it is getting an unexpected EOF.  The framing of the data may be different between good and bad.  It is hard to say if this is a client or server issue.  It looks like TLS 1.3 is first tried and then TLS 1,2,  Also HTTP 1.1 is being used.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and verify that c# is doing the same.

Comment: I have solved the problem and you can find the solution in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/55227

Comment: @MarceloOliveto the problem isn't ASP.NET Core 5. The very link you posted shows you're trying to use insecure settings. The real solution is to fix whatever service requires weak ciphers, not weaken *your* sevice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I basically running into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

I resolved the issue following this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45244

I have modified the following in the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

1. Add System default section bellow oid section

```
# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file               = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section             = new_oids

# System default
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

2. Add at end of file the default section

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
#CipherString = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-S>
#CipherString = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-S>
```

The CipherString generated from https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.7&config=old&openssl=1.1.1d&guideline=5.6 doesn't work for me

But the following works fine
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1

The last thing to check was the route of openssl.cnf because in my case Ubuntu 18.04 when i put:

> openssl version -d
> OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"

And in this path was another openssl.cnf of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

> mv /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf.bak
> ln -s /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

It's very important to restart the api or application to see the changes

Comment: That's a very bad idea and no solution at all. Fix the service that requires weak ciphers instead of weakening security

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you read the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux 

".NET, on Linux, now respects the OpenSSL configuration for default cipher suites when doing TLS/SSL via the SslStream class or higher-level operations, such as HTTPS via the HttpClient class. When default cipher suites aren't explicitly configured, .NET on Linux uses a tightly restricted list of permitted cipher suites"

Because about this, i ajusted the security to TLSv1.2 and upper to solve it

Comment: The docs don't say what you think they do. They say .NET Core 5 uses *more secure ciphers* ciphers. You enabled weaker ciphers. The real solution is to fix the service to use the stronger ciphers

Comment: To put it another way, **why** do you insist on weakening the client instead of strengthening the service?

Comment: I am consuming a service. The service does not belong to me because it is from a provider side. 
I am not the owner of the service

Comment: Don't claim you run into any issue with .NET or Ubuntu then. It's a quirk of the service.

Comment: With asp.net core 3.1 client and from curl command on linux was working. But in asp.net core 5.0 don't work because With 5.0 the default ciphers are limit to what is currently believed to be strong and safe ciphers

Comment: I confirm, this is working in Alpine 3.14.

Answer (score 0):

Change your httpclienthandler to add certificate in the following way, I would recommend not to change much onto cipher unless it unavoidable. Following works with dotnet 6.0 alpine build

```
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadWrite))
        {
            var certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certs.Import(settings.Value.ClientCertPath, settings.Value.ClientCertSecret, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certs)
            {
                if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
                {
                    ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
                }
                else
                {
                    store.Add(cert);
                }
            }
            store.Close();
        }
```